# JavaScript Explosion Physics for a bunch of Divs

Tags: javascript

I don't know how I should proceed with this.

**The situation**
I have a bunch of divs all absolutely positioned relative to the document.body. I know each div's size and position. I also have the position of an explosion origin point.

**The goal**
What I would like to do is simulate an explosion at the explosion origin point and have all the divs fly away from the explosion but eventually come to a stop. i.e. simulating an explosion.

Are they're any physics formula gurus out there that could tell me what formulas I'll need to use? My guess is something similar to giving the explosion point some sort of mass and using this to work out the div's velocities.

I'd like to make a good job of this, so I'm not really interested in any short cut formulas that would produce a less realistic effect.

If there exists any efficient, lightweight JavaScript physics libraries that would make this task easier that would be great to. Although do not want anything jQuery based as I'll need to keep this as lightweight as possible. And no libraries that have a whole code base to work with the canvas element as this will just add a bulk of un-needed code.

Thanks in advance, Ali.

**Back story, not really relative to the question above, feel free to ignore**
The reason I implement this as I thought it would be nice for some epic page transition effects. So I want to transition by exploding all the main visible divs.

I've implemented so far some code that replaces a large div in the viewport with a bunch of smaller divs ready to explode.

Here is my implementation so far. You will see references to functions that arn't native to JavaScript, this is because I'm using the Closure library, it would be to much to show everything.

```
/**
 * @constructor
  */
 pwd.fx.Explode = function (div) {
     this.element_ = div;
 }


 /**
  * @public
  */
 pwd.fx.Explode.prototype.play = function () {
     this.viewportOffset = goog.style.getViewportPageOffset(document);
     this.size = goog.style.getBounds(this.element_);
     this.position = goog.style.getClientPosition(this.element_);
     this.backgroundColour = goog.style.getBackgroundColor(this.element_);

     // Set the explosion centre
     // relative to the viewport
     this.explosionEpicentre = new goog.math.Coordinate(
         this.position.x + Math.floor(this.size.width / 2),
         this.position.y + Math.floor(this.size.height / 2)
     );

     this.seperate();
 }

 /**
  * @private
  * Seperates the current div into loads of little divs
  */
 pwd.fx.Explode.prototype.seperate = function () {
     var idealSize = new goog.math.Size(35, 35);
     var widths = pwd.math.algorithms.getExactFit(idealSize.width, this.size.width);
     var heights = pwd.math.algorithms.getExactFit(idealSize.height, this.size.height);

     // Remove the node as it will be replaced by blocks
     goog.dom.removeNode(this.element_);

     var cumulativeHeight = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < heights.length; i++) {
         var cumulativeWidth = 0;
         for (var j = 0; j < widths.length; j++) {
             var blockSize = new goog.math.Size(widths[j], heights[i]);
             var blockRelativePosition = new goog.math.Coordinate(cumulativeWidth, cumulativeHeight);
             cumulativeWidth += widths[j];
             var blockPosition = new goog.math.Coordinate.sum(this.position, blockRelativePosition);
             // Add the block
             this.addBlock(blockSize, blockPosition, this.backgroundColour);
         }
         cumulativeHeight += heights[i];
     }
 }

 /**
  * Add a block
  * All positions are relative to the viewport
  * @private
  */
 pwd.fx.Explode.prototype.addBlock = function (blockSize, blockPosition, backgroundColour) {
     var block = document.createElement("div");

     // Height and width
     block.style.width = blockSize.width + "px";
     block.style.height = blockSize.height + "px";

     // Positioning
     block.style.position = "absolute";
     block.style.left = this.viewportOffset.x + blockPosition.x + "px";
     block.style.top = this.viewportOffset.y + blockPosition.y + "px";

     // Styling
     block.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColour;

     // Add to document relative to viewport
     document.body.appendChild(block);

     // Explode block
     // TODO...?
 }
```

Comment: The title is amusing - see http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=div for the urban dictionary for div and the word "bunch" sets it off.

Comment: On a serious note - what have you tried? This is not a free coding factory.

Comment: Ha! Didn't interpret it like that. Don't get me wrong I'm not after a free solution. I'm just after some guidance to start down the right path first time. I find this stuff quite complex. At this point I've just done some research, I haven't tried expanding my code further yet as I don't know how to proceed with it.

Comment: Why not post what you have done so far. As to a possible solution look into vector maths and also an equation to simulate how a particle slows down (is it linear for example).

Comment: I've added my code so far, it basically does my setting up of the situation of where I've currently arrived at. And thanks for the tips.

Comment: Have you got the HTML. Why not put it into fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: It wasn't straight forward, fiddle doesn't really easily support the closure library so I just compiled all my code into one file. It's not exactly easy to debug like this but you can see it working.
http://jsfiddle.net/jD7MJ/1/
All this does is convert the div into lots of small divs ready to explode.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the space bar and enter key on your computer?

Comment: I don't get your question. If your referring to the compressed JavaScript code, that's because that's the only way I could get my example onto fiddle. I use http://plovr.com/ to develop my code, if you wanted to see what it does.

Comment: The whole point of fiddle is to be able to fiddle with it - i.e. it is readable in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to ask on a physics forum. You just need to know the basics of newtonian mechanics. Give your objects a mass. Calculate the net forces acting upon each one at any one point in time. (The explosion, and gravity). Given that force, you calculate the acceleration at any one point in time. Given the acceleration, if constant over time t, it will change the velocity by v. It gets a bit more complicated if you have them coming to rest, that will bring bouncing and friction into play. Bouncing is quite simple - if velocity is v, and bounce coefficient is a, then on bounce, the velocity becomes -va. To calculate the force that friction applies, it's proportional to the force pushing the objects together. Frictional force = friction coefficient for the pair of surfaces x force pushing them together. (It has nothing to do with their surface area believe it or not - well, in most cases.)  To do these calculations in 2D, you will be splitting your forces, accelerations, velocities etc into two components, x and y. This is easy if you know your way round a right angle triangle. (Sin, Cosine, Tan, Pythagoras). Finally, if you want your divs colliding with each other, you'll need to know about conservation of momentum and possibly conservation of energy, I can't remember how all that works.

I presume you don't want your divs rotating. Angular velocities and momentum and all that is complicated in comparison.

Comment: Cheers, this gives me some new things to look into, and yes I would like to rotate too but I figured one step at a time :). I'm not worried to much about bouncing, could be interesting to have the divs bouncing off each other though but I don't think it would add much to the visual effect. I find this a lot to take in, probably going to have to read your answer many times before I understand it.

Comment: You're probably better off focusing on separate tutorials on the net. One for newton's laws of motion. Then one for 2d newtonian mechanics. Then one for the bouncing, then one for the friction. But if you're dealing with rotations you're going to have one heck of a challenge. I suggest going for a pre-written library for that. Efficient calculations for that are advanced, you'll want to be familiar with matrices, and possibly imaginary numbers - I can't remember exactly, quite happy to have forgotten all that.

Comment: Excellent starting points thanks. Last time I learnt about imaginary numbers I found it pretty interesting so I might enjoy this for a while before I want to pull my hair out :P